# Host the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS on google cloud storage not working

Tags: django, google-oauth, render.com

What is the best way of accessing the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS json file ? I tried hosting it on Google cloud storage and the link is public, but can't work in Django . I am using redner.com as my server.